# Galera Mariadb Multi-Master Replication

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I am trying to setup a cluster of 3 servers in 3 different locations; Dallas-US, London-UK, Mumbai-India. On each location I have setup a webserver and db server. On db server I have configured Galera Mariadb Multi-Master cluster to replicate db among all three servers. My each webservers are connected with local IP to their regional db server. I am expecting that my Dallas webserver will fetch db records from Dallas db server only; London webserver from London db server only and Mumbai webserver from Mumbai db server only. So I am having this setup

Dallas: 1 Webserver, 1 db server connected to webserver with local IP

London: 1 Webserver, 1 db server connected to webserver with local IP

Mumbai: 1 Webserver, 1 db server connected to webserver with local IP

Everything is working well but I have found that mysql query takes much time above 100s while fetching record. I have tried Mariadb with single instance and its fetching data within 5s.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to setup something like this where every db server will geo-replicate its data but every webserver will fetch data only from its local db server?

Answer (score 0):

The performance is going to be atrocious with your setup, especially in writes because every write has to be acknowledged by at least one remote node. You will also get an astronomical number of deadlocks.

If you need geo-replicated synchronous redundancy, you would be batter off with with DRBD for block level replication. Performance will still be terrible on commit latency but not as terrible as with Galera.

You need to rethink your requirements and your approach to fulfilling them.

Comment: At the moment I am using read operation only from 3 different locations and write from 1 location only. What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: Its read operation only taking time above 100s. For simple query fetching from single table it executes in a timely manner. But for queries from multiple tables takes above 100s.

Comment: An educated guess would be that it is keeping track of what records are touched by the query and exchanging this between the nodes to ensure a consistent view across MVC instances. If you can afford to lose any in-flight transactions if you lose a node,  asynchronous master-master replication will perform well. If you can't afford to lose any transactions, putting your datadir on DRBD will perform as a single node on reads.

Comment: After lots of investigation and contacting their community forum, this issue was supposed to be a bug in Galera Cluster software. It happens only on certain queries.